# RTK Query with two different apis works only with one

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have two different Api. Both uses RTK query to do different set of CRUD operations. One of them works perfectly fine but the other one shows error

```
TypeError: (0 , _api_addressApi__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.useGetAddress) is not a 
function
```

Here is my `addressApi.js` which does not work

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

export const addressApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "address",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://random-data-api.com/api/v2",
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getAddress: builder.query({
      query: () => {
        return { url: "/addresses" };
      },
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetAddress } = addressApi;
```

Here is my `store.js`

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import { addressApi } from "../api/addressApi";
import { destinationApi } from "../api/destinationApi";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    // destinationApi works but addressApi does not works
    [destinationApi.reducerPath]: destinationApi.reducer,
    [addressApi.reducerPath]: addressApi.reducer,
  },
  // Adding the api middleware enables caching, invalidation, polling,
  // and other useful features of `rtk-query`.
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware()
      .concat(destinationApi.middleware)
      .concat(addressApi.middleware),
});
```

In the file where I am calling `useGetAddress()`

```
  import { useGetAddress } from "../api/addressApi";
  function AddDestination() {
  ....
  const { data, error } = useGetAddress();
  console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide method:'GET' to query

Like

```
getAddress: builder.query({
  query: () => {
    return { url: "/addresses" ,
             method:'GET',
           };
           },
```